# Anomalous test -v results with bash associative array

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, associative-array

Ran across this apparent anomaly. Test code:

```bash
(
    set -x
    declare -A a=()
    for i in x "'" '"'
    do
        a[$i]=
        test -v a[$i] && true
    done
    : "${!a[@]}"
)
```

Output:

```
+ a=()
+ declare -A a
+ for i in x "'" '"'
+ a[$i]=
+ test -v 'a[x]'
+ true
+ for i in x "'" '"'
+ a[$i]=
+ test -v 'a['\'']'
+ for i in x "'" '"'
+ a[$i]=
+ test -v 'a["]'
+ : \' '"' x
```

I would have expected `true` to be executed three times, not just the once. It seems that `test -v` fails for associative array elements where the index expands into something containing a quote character.

Is this a bash bug, or just me needing better-informed expectations?

Comment: Interesting question. Do you get the same effect, if you write `test -v "a[$i]"` or `[[ -v a[$i] ]]`?

Comment: It seems `\ `,  `[` and `]` also behave this way :-o

Comment: Also, `a['"x"']` gives false, but it gives true if preceded by `a[x]=`.

Comment: Turns out it's just me needing better-informed expectations; this behaviour, like so much shell behaviour, becomes unsurprising once you learn to tilt your head just so and squint a bit. Added an answer of my own below to explain more fully. Thanks to choroba for the observations about `\ `, `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug.

I've found a workaround, though:

```
declare -A a=()
for i in x '"a"' a '"a"' ']' '[' '\' "'" '"' y
do
    a[$i]=
    test -v 'a[$i]' && true
done
```

Comment: whoops - looks like I actually edited away somebody else's comment instead of just adding one. The original commenter was expressing some confusion about how the $i expansion actually managed to happen even inside single quotes. Apologies to whoever that was.

Comment: In fact it's not being expanded within the single quotes; everything enclosed inside those single quotes is passed exactly as-is to the test builtin as an argument. The expansion of $i doesn't happen until test -v processes that argument, which I'm guessing it does using code shared with that used to parse the left hand side of variable assignments within shell command lines. If you don't force bash to defer the expansion of $i that way, it ends up double-parsing it like eval would, which screws things up. Same rules appear to apply to the unset builtin.

Comment: @flabdablet: What's weird is that `[[ -v ... ]]` works the same way, but e.g. `[[ -f $file ]]` works without quotes even for filenames containing spaces.

Comment: That's documented behaviour, though: see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html - "The words between the [[ and ]] do not undergo word splitting and filename expansion. The shell performs tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, command substitution, process substitution, and quote removal on those words (the expansions that would occur if the words were enclosed in double quotes). Conditional operators such as ‘-f’ must be unquoted to be recognized as primaries."

Comment: The differences between `[[ ... ]]` and `[ ... ]` / `test ...` are down to the status of `[[ ... ]]` as a specific piece of the language much like `if ...` or `while ...` or `case ...`, while `[` and `test` are ordinary commands, albeit builtin. I believe bash went that way just because trying to implement conditional expressions as ordinary command arguments has so many extraordinarily common failure modes.

Answer (score 1):

OK, sussed it.

This works:

```bash
(
    set -x
    declare -A a=()
    a[x]= a["'"]= a['"']=
    for i in x "'" '"' y
    do
        test -v 'a[$i]' && true
    done
    : "${!a[@]}"
)
```

Output:

```
+ a=()
+ declare -A a
+ a[x]=
+ a["'"]=
+ a['"']=
+ for i in x "'" '"' y
+ test -v 'a[$i]'
+ true
+ for i in x "'" '"' y
+ test -v 'a[$i]'
+ true
+ for i in x "'" '"' y
+ test -v 'a[$i]'
+ true
+ for i in x "'" '"' y
+ test -v 'a[$i]'
+ : \' '"' x
```

Now, the only `test -v` that fails is the one for the array element `a[y]` which was indeed never set.

The unwritten rule appears to be that the `name` argument supplied to `test -v name` gets dealt with in exactly the same way as whatever can go on the left hand side of the `=` in a shell variable assignment as the shell parses command lines. Specifically, any expansion syntax inside the subscript portion of any such `name` will be evaluated before testing whether the resulting name has a referent. Furthermore, to make quote removal operate correctly, such expansions *have to be* deferred in that way; they can't be allowed to happen before `name` gets passed as an argument to `test`.

Same appears to apply to names supplied as arguments to `unset`.

Closest I can find to this in the bash manual is this paragraph in the [section on arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html):

> When using a variable name with a subscript as an argument to a
> command, such as with unset, without using the word expansion syntax
> described above, the argument is subject to the shell’s filename
> expansion. If filename expansion is not desired, the argument should
> be quoted.

which strikes me as kind of tangential to the issue at hand. And I don't think it's just variable expansion: I think it goes the full Monty. Try `unset 'a[x$(ls -al >&2)]'` if you feel like having a bit of a shudder; might be a fun little class of script injection vulnerabilities lurking in there.

Summarizing: if you're going to use `test -v` to test for the existence of an entry in an associative array, wrap the name in single quotes, not double quotes, even if it includes expansions of other variables. You want `test -v 'a[$i]'`, not anything that expands the same way as `test -v "a[$i]"` would. Same applies to `unset`.

Comment: Regarding your closing comments, I believe [BashPitfalls/061](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B.5B_-v_hash.5B.24key.5D_.5D.5D) is relevant.

Comment: Oh, that site is *gold*. Thanks, @tjm3772!